# Visual Studio Code and TSLint: Code wrap to more than 80 characters

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, word-wrap, tslint, prettier

I'm using TypeScript with TSLint and Prettier in Visual Studio Code to write a React Native App.

I tried to configure my editor to wrap the code in per line automatically to 100 characters. But after saving it's always 80 characters, not 100.

Here are the settings I changed:

```
"prettier.tslintIntegration": true,
"prettier.printWidth": 100,
"editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
"editor.rulers": [100],
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 100,
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

And this is my `tslint.json`:

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier"],
  "rules": {
    // "jsx-no-lambda": false,
    "member-access": false,
    "interface-name": false,
    "max-line-length": [true, 100]
  }
}
```

Even though I configured everything this way, my code still automatically wraps around 80 characters. How can I get that to stop?

If my line exceeds 100 characters I get a linting error, so the `tslint.json` setting seems to work.

Bonus: Complete VSCode settings in case I missed something:

```
{
  "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  "prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
  "prettier.tslintIntegration": true,
  "prettier.printWidth": 100,
  "editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
  "editor.rulers": [100],
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
  },
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    // "statusBar.background": "#272b33",
    // "panel.background": "#30353f",
    // "sideBar.background": "#2a2b33",
    "editor.background": "#2c313a"
  },
  "todohighlight.keywords": [
    {
      "text": "DEBUG:",
      "color": "#fff",
      "backgroundColor": "limegreen",
      "overviewRulerColor": "grey"
    },
    {
      "text": "NOTE:",
      "color": "#fff",
      "backgroundColor": "mediumslateblue",
      "overviewRulerColor": "grey"
    },
    {
      "text": "REVIEW:",
      "color": "#fff",
      "backgroundColor": "dodgerblue",
      "overviewRulerColor": "grey"
    },
    {
      "text": "XXX:",
      "color": "#fff",
      "backgroundColor": "orangered",
      "overviewRulerColor": "grey"
    }
  ],
  "editor.wordWrapColumn": 100,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These two should be enough:

```
"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 100
```

Seems like `"editor.wordWrap"` is missing in your settings. In vscode this setting controls wrapping policy: "wordWrapColumn" means wrap at `"editor.wordWrapColumn"` setting.

You can also try `"editor.wordWrap": "bounded"` which will respect "wordWrapColumn", but also wrap if your viewport is less than nuber of columns you define.

UPD: Based on our discussion in comments, it seems that prettier do not respect its `"printWidth"` settings. There might be two most probable reasons:

1. This issue: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/595
2. Priorities for defining configuration options: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#prettiers-settings. In particular, it first searches for prettier [config files](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html), than for [.editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/) files, and only then for vscode settings.

As a workaround you can try to actually define this setting in prettier config file for your project, or in editorconfig file and check if vscode plugin will work with either of those.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't fix the issue. If I hit save, the code still gets wrapped to less than 80 characters :(

Comment: Am I right that it wraps correctly until you hit "Save"? If so, can you try this with prettier disabled?

Comment: If I disable Prettier or set `"prettier.tslintIntegration": false` the code stays at it's character count. But I like to keep Prettier As for the `tslintIntegration` I'm not quite sure what it does. But since I'm using TypeScript with TSLint I suppose it's useful.

Comment: Cool! Than it seems like a vscode plugin prettier issue. First, it's not only you: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/595
Second, check for other configuration files that might overwrite your vscode rule, this plugin searched for prettier config file, and for .editorconfig file. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Working with a `.prettierrc.json` file! Thank you It's not ideal and I have no Idea what is overwriting this setting, but it is a start I guess.

Comment: Glad it helped! Most probably it's a bug in vscode plugin, so the answer is in its internals.

Answer (score 15):

I found the easiest way which worked for me. Go into settings search for `Print Width` and set `Prettier: Print Width` to according to your need, by default it's 80 I changed it to 150 and it works for me. And add following in your settings.json 
`"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 150,
"prettier.printWidth": 150`

[image]

Comment: This also controls the breakpoint for when function splitting/wrapping occurs and whether or not the params in the function will be line-by-line, or all on one line

Answer (score 8):

find or add a file named .prettierrc.js and add `printWidth` as shown bellow

```
module.exports = {
  bracketSpacing: false,
  jsxBracketSameLine: true,
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  arrowParens: 'avoid',
  printWidth: 150, // <== add this
};
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Once there's `.prettierrc` file present and it is not COMPLETELY empty, but contains at least `{}`, VSCode ignores  my rule `"prettier.printWidth": 120` set in `.vscode/settings.json` and uses the default `80`. That actually makes sense - if there is `.prettierrc` config, it ensures that prettier will be consistent even if someone uses a different IDE/editor than VSCode that has Prettier plugin, in which case `.vscode/settings.json` would have no effect.

Answer (score 5):

I had prettier installed, adding only the below line was enough, to solve the issue:

```
"prettier.printWidth": 120,
```

General wrap lengths are 80 & 120, but some use 150.

You can add above in either of below settings:

Project workspace settings:

- `.vscode\settings.json`

User settings:

- `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`

Paths above are for Windows OS, but similar ones will be for other OS.

Answer (score 2):

In tslint.json, you should be able to add `printWidth` to the Prettier config section:

```
"rules": {
    "prettier": [
        true,
        {
            "printWidth": 100
        }
    ],
```

As [vaglignatev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3606603/valignatev) mentioned, you'll need to install `tslint-config-prettier`.

Comment: Should probably mention that tslint-config-prettier have to be installed for it to work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for me the *.editorconfig* was overriding the prettier settings.
I just added *max_line_length = 100*

Comment: Please take the time to provide context and source code with your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).